# 2 Different Models Need to Utilize Same View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, models

Let me premise this by saying I am transitioning from Classic ASP to .net so my .net knowledge is all through books, not use. I am working on a shopping cart platform and have been tasked with creating 3 different display types (horizontal slider, vertical slider and grid) that will be able to be utilized by 2 different models.

I got the new views to work with my first model and thought I was in the clear and plugged in the second, but then I started getting an error about the models not being the same. I am trying to figure out what the best way to handle this. The solutions I have come up with are

1. Using A View Model - this seems like it is supposed to only be used when you need to combine 2 models into one and that is really the opposite of what I need, I need to make 1 view work for 2 models.
2. Make separate views for each type. This seems logical but is going to result in 5 new view files that are almost identical to those I have already created, it seemed redundant.
3. Use renderPartial and convert the models - not really sure how I would even accomplish this, but my though was to renderpartial out the creation of the actual displays (horizontal slider, vertical slider and grid view)

I am having a hard time determining what the best course of action is. I know that with MVC and .net you are supposed to never code the same thing twice and I think making the separate views is doing exactly that. Any thoughts on how to best approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A view is a visual representation of your model, so if you have 2 different model to display, you need 2 different views (or partial views)

Comment: Originally the 2 different models would each go to their own views but then both end in the same view, but they were both sent to this same view different ways, one used an Html.Action that I am guessing was used to convert it and the other used a DisplayFor, so that was why I assumed this could be done by reusing the same views.

Comment: Not clear what you meant by your last comment, but if the views are _almost identical_ then you can use a main view or layout for common html and partial views (`Html.Partial()` or `@Html.Action()` or `EditorTemplates` for the model specific html.

Comment: A ViewModel is intended to encapsulate the information required by the View. I don't understand why you don't make another ViewModel that encapsulates everything you need all into one?

Comment: The best way to use more than one model in a view is Partial view. If other model uses is not major or you want to use its one property then use viewbag or viewdata in action method

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I'm doing it right now on my project, I don't know if it's the best way or not but for me works fine.

Basically on my website's homepage I need to have to 2 different models to handle 2 forms posting to the same Method in the controller

```
namespace Website.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class HomePageModels
    {
        public SearchFlyModel SearchFly { get; set; }
        public CarRequestModel CarRequest { get; set; }      
        public int form { get; set; }

        public HomePageModels()
        {
            SearchFly = new SearchFlyModel();
            CarRequest = new CarRequestModel();
        }
    }
}
```

Then on the controller's method I need to know which form was posted to know which form I need to validate, because Asp.net automatically validate the model , it will ,by default validate both models in your ViewModel , and this affects the ModelState and when you check if your model is valid doing ModelState.isValid , this will return false because you only posted one form and not the other which is completely empty.

To manage that, I do the following

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(HomePageModels model)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();

            if (model.form == 0)
            {
                try
                {                                        
                    ValidateModel(model.SearchFly);
                    return this.SearchFly(model.SearchFly);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    ValidateModel(model.CarRequest);
                    return this.SearchCar(model.CarRequest);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }


            var modelHomePage = new HomePageModels()
            {
                SearchFly = model.SearchFly,
                CarRequest = model.CarRequest,
                form=model.form
            };
            return View(modelHomePage);
        }
```

Both forms are posting to the same action because I need to return the form's validations error so the user can fix it.